# How to change an array of .. arrays and subarrays (and subsubarray) to a simple array in regex (trough javascript?)

Tags: javascript, regex, select

I have the following question. I have a multidimensional arrays that i'd like to convert in a single dimension, so in can loop trough them as an array. I pasted the entire code in pastebin  (https://pastebin.com/kitjY8CG).

My hope is to try and do this with regex. However, i have a limited idea on how to go about this.. The easiest would be to get regex to select everything between parenthesis and change it into an array in the end.
Is this possible?

```
[
[["https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=4589232","https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=4737287","https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=5054137","https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=4776617" [..] ],["https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=4899728" [..] ,"https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=2650424" "https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=3807271"]],[["https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=2834602 .. "https://www.website.be/set.aspx?Id=3807271"]],[[ .....
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: why regex instead of simple array.flat() ?

Comment: Hi there, i did not know "array.flat()" existed :-)

Comment: well you know now :) I would appreciate an upvote.

Comment: i want to ..  but i need 15 reputation points to cast a vote :

Comment: dont worry about it then!

Answer (score 0):

If your array is an actual array and not a string.

```
yourArray.flat();
```